# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'slack' while running Docker container

Tags: python, docker, slack, slack-api

I have written a small script to send messages to a slack channel using `slackclient`. The script works fine when ran on its own, but when I try to containerize it it fails to find (install?) slack.

The Dockerfile

```
FROM python:latest

WORKDIR /app
COPY bot.py .
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libpython3-dev
RUN pip3 install pip_chill
RUN pip-chill --no-version > requirements.txt

COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT [ "python3", "bot.py" ]
```

The `requirements.txt` file

```
autopep8
iterm2
pip-chill
python-dotenv
six
slackclient // includes slack
libpython3.6-dev
```

Then, I build and run the container - in the directory where `Dockerfile`, `bot.py` and `requirements.txt` is - in the following way:

```
docker build -t bot:1.0 .

docker run -it --name mybot bot:1.0 .
```

And I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/bot.py", line 1, in <module>
    import slack
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'slack'
```

If I remove that import everything works fine

Comment: You overwrite your requirements file in this line `RUN pip-chill --no-version > requirements.txt`, you probably mean to run `pip install` instead?

Comment: Assuming that  `RUN pip-chill --no-version > requirements.txt` populates *requirements.txt* (although then `COPY requirements.txt .` doesn't make any sense), you should add below it: `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt`.